# TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BaseRepository_1'

Tags: typescript

I'm getting TS2451 error while compiling my project. I've spend few days trying fix this, but no answer found on google helped me.

Here is my *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "api/node_modules/@types",
      "api/@types",
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@api/*": ["api/src/*"],
    },
    "types": ["node"]
  },  
  "exclude": [
    "api/node_modules",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts",
  ]
}
```

*BaseRepository.ts*

```
import knex from "@api/configs/knex.config";
import { Knex } from "knex";

export default abstract class BaseRepository<T> {
  private knex: Knex = null;
  private tableName: string = null;

  constructor(tableName: string) {
    this.knex = knex;
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

  private get query(): Knex.QueryBuilder {
    return this.knex(this.tableName);
  }

  async find(item: Partial<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    return await this.query.where(item).select();
  }
}
```

*UsersRepository.ts* & *SalesRepository.ts* only extends BaseRepository class and call super() on constructor

And error which I'm getting

```
[ERROR] 14:56:42 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/repositories/UsersRepository.ts:6:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BaseRepository_1'.

6 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("./BaseRepository"));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/repositories/SalesRepository.ts:6:7
    6 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("./BaseRepository"));
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'BaseRepository_1' was also declared here.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error message by copying contents of `src/repositories/*.js` files and pasting into corresponding `src/repositories/*.ts` files (sic!). Please double check if your `.ts` files still contain your TypeScript code -- not the compiled output. It seems your source files were overwritten somehow.

Here is exact output of `tsc`:

```
src/repositories/SalesRepository.ts:11:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BaseRepository_1'.

11 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("src/BaseRepository"));
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/repositories/UsersRepository.ts:11:7
    11 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("src/BaseRepository"));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'BaseRepository_1' was also declared here.

src/repositories/UsersRepository.ts:11:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'BaseRepository_1'.

11 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("src/BaseRepository"));
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/repositories/SalesRepository.ts:11:7
    11 const BaseRepository_1 = __importDefault(require("src/BaseRepository"));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'BaseRepository_1' was also declared here.


Found 2 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     1  src/repositories/SalesRepository.ts:11
     1  src/repositories/UsersRepository.ts:11
```

Comment: My `.ts` files still contain TypeScript code...

Comment: Well, unless you have better idea, try to find why `tsc` compiles already compiled `.js` file. Could it be some cached version of your project? Wrong path? Error messages are exactly the same, that's a huge red flag.